# Loop Object and Array when Array is inside of an Object

Tags: arrays, json, loops

I am using a query to receive a JSON response. I would like to loop each object (VGF, SSR, BCV, etc..) and output them to premade divs, then the arrays within those objects will loop and create divs within that matching object container.

This is a shortened down version of what I have, and it works mostly. (hopefully, I haven't screwed it up here).

The problem is I have to repeat the searchresult function by copying and pasting the entire function for each object (VGF, SSR, BCV, etc). I would really like to learn how to loop this and not have the same code pasted more than a dozen times.

If I have messed up or left something out of this question, please let me know and I will take care of it.

Here is my ajax request and javascript. I know my problem lies within this loop. I have tried to do a loop inside of a loop, etc. But, when I do that I get no results at all. I am baffled and ready to learn.

```
$(function getData() {
  $("#searchbtn").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: "action.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {},
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        searchresult(response);
      }
      });
  });
});

let searchresult = function(response) {
      let container = document.getElementById('VGFresults');
      let output = "";
      for (let j = 0; j < response.length; j++) {
            if (response[j].rcode == "VGF") {
               output +=
               `<div id="person${response[j].code}">
                <p>${response[j].firstname} ${response[j].lastname}</p>    
                </div>`
            }
      $(container).html(output);
      }
};
```

Here is my response (Same layout as I am currently receiving but shortened the objects in the arrays).

```
response =
{"VGF":
   [{"code":"TU","rcode":"VGF","firstname":"Tom","lastname":"Riddle"},
    {"code":"AZ","rcode":"VGF","firstname":"Harry","lastname":"Potter"},
    {"code":"FR","rcode":"VGF","firstname":"Hermoine","lastname":"Granger"}],

"SSR":
   [{"code":"HG","rcode":"SSR","firstname":"Walt","lastname":"Disney"},
    {"code":"TR","rcode":"SSR","firstname":"H.R.","lastname":"Pickins"},
    {"code":"ED","rcode":"SSR","firstname":"Tom","lastname":"Ford"}],

"BCV":
   [{"code":"YH","rcode":"BCV","firstname":"Tom","lastname":"Clancy"},
    {"code":"RS","rcode":"BCV","firstname":"Robin","lastname":"Williams"},
    {"code":"AB","rcode":"BCV","firstname":"Brett","lastname":"Favre"}]}
```

Here is the HTML that the searchresult function is working with. Currently, it works fine.

To clarify, I would like each object to insert its arrays within the corresponding div. Example:
SSR arrays will go into `<div id="SSRresults">`
BCV arrays will go into `<div id="BCVresults">`

From there, each array will create a div within that *results div for each array.

```
<div id="VGFresults">
  <div id="VGFheader">This is the VGF Header</div>
  <div id="VGFresults">The Javascript Creates Divs for each array here.</div>
</div>

<div id="SSRresults">
  <div id="SSRheader">This is the SSR Header</div>
  <div id="SSRresults">The Javascript Creates Divs for each array here.</div>
</div>

<div id="BCVresults">
  <div id="BCVheader">This is the BCV Header</div>
  <div id="BCVresults">The Javascript Creates Divs for each array here.</div>
</div>
```

Thanks, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hopefully in your real code you've not neglected to close the quotes on the IDs in the results divs.

Comment: that's just a typo here. The real code works, I just can't seem to loop those initial objects. I will fix it within my question though. Thanks.

Comment: You have a line `console.log(response);`. Right after that put `console.log(response.length);`. You use that later so it better be what you think it is.

Comment: I haven't double-checked but see if [this](https://zellwk.com/blog/looping-through-js-objects/) helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this:

I declare the response as variable (but sure it will work with your ajax response.

```js
var response =
{"VGF":
   [{"code":"TU","rcode":"VGF","firstname":"Tom","lastname":"Riddle"},
    {"code":"AZ","rcode":"VGF","firstname":"Harry","lastname":"Potter"},
    {"code":"FR","rcode":"VGF","firstname":"Hermoine","lastname":"Granger"}],

"SSR":
   [{"code":"HG","rcode":"SSR","firstname":"Walt","lastname":"Disney"},
    {"code":"TR","rcode":"SSR","firstname":"H.R.","lastname":"Pickins"},
    {"code":"ED","rcode":"SSR","firstname":"Tom","lastname":"Ford"}],

"BCV":
   [{"code":"YH","rcode":"BCV","firstname":"Tom","lastname":"Clancy"},
    {"code":"RS","rcode":"BCV","firstname":"Robin","lastname":"Williams"},
    {"code":"AB","rcode":"BCV","firstname":"Brett","lastname":"Favre"}]}



let searchresult = function(response) {
//          let container = document.getElementById('VGFresults');

      let output = "";
      for (var key in response) {
         // skip loop if the property is from prototype
            if (!response.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

            var obj = response[key];
            let container = document.getElementById(key+'results');
            for (var prop in obj) {
                // skip loop if the property is from prototype
                if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;

                // your code
                //alert(prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
                console.log(obj[prop])
                 output += "<div id="+prop+"><p>"+obj[prop].firstname+" "+ obj[prop].lastname+"</p></div>"
            }
        }

             
      container.innerText = output;
      console.log(output);
};
```

```html
<div id="VGFresults"></div>
```

each property VGF, SSR, BCV and so on can be handled now.

EDIT: based on users request, I guess you can edit the selector like this:
let container = document.getElementById(key+'results');

Comment: Okay so, it is outputting the text. But it is putting it all under <div id="vgfresults"> I am trying to put each object within it's matching div. So, object VGF will go into <div id="vgfresults">. Object SSR will go into <div id="SSRresults">. Object BCV will go into <div id="BCVresults">, etc.

Comment: Maybe you can adapt this. There are lots of Q&As about looping `obj.hasOwnProperty()`.

Comment: I am trying. I seem to have no issues looping each array. But I can't for the life of me figure out looping each object that holds the array. As stated before, I can copy and paste the cost, but I am trying to stay away from repeating code as the project already seems pretty big. I'm still googling though. I appreciate the help, nevertheless.

Comment: @BunsenHoneydew I have adapted the code based on your last comment. Does this solve your question now? The container id is now dynamic addressed.

Comment: I get container is not defined. It looks the same on my screen lack commenting out this line: //let container = document.getElementById('VGFresults');

Edit: I see the new line, but it still gives not defined.
let container = document.getElementById(key+'results');

Comment: Okay, I saw my problem and fixed the not defined. However, the container is showing up as null.

Comment: I ran console.log(container) and that's what I am getting (null). The rest of it looks good. I think you are on the right track, just gotta figure out why it's null.

Comment: try to look into the output. what does it say? console.log(output); is it also emty?

Comment: I got it! In my html file, i had the div id as vgfresults (lowercase). Once I changed them to VGFresults (uppercase) to match the javascript. I may see another issue though, looking into it.

Comment: @pixelquadrat It's looping them weird.  Here is a link to a screenshot. I realize roomcode and resortcode aren't the example I gave but here is my output line and link:

output += "<div id='room"+obj[prop].roomcode+"' class='"+obj[prop].resortcode+ " roomresults'><p></div>"

notice I have the resortcode set as class, this is for testing purpose to make sure the rooms are looping under the correct object. All of the VGF rooms are also outputting with SSR.

https://pasteboard.co/K5NncCw.png

Comment: @BunsenHoneydew you are totally welcome here :). But I guess you should update your question or create a new one. discussions within the comment section arent helpful and I have to say, I really don`t catch your point here. If the answer based on your question solved the main issue, please mark as answered. cheers, richard

Comment: @pixelquadrat I appreciate all of your help, and this has moved me forward a bit. The issue is, the loop isn't stopping after its turn. So BCV results into the BCV container, then it fills the VGF container with both BCV and VGF, then when it loops to the SSR container it fills it with BCV, VGF, and SSR results. Again, I appreciate all of your help as I understand it a bit better, but it seems to be causing an infinite loop into each container.